# Why just one serial(/dev/ser1) I can find on Beaglebone Black which running QNX

Tags: beagleboneblack, qnx

My Beaglebone Black can find 5 serial devices under Linux, but after I make it boot into QNX, just one serial device can found. I wonder if the QNX serial driver for BBB just support 1 serial or have some ways to setup for supporting more serials.

The QNX bsp version is 6.5.0, I download it form [Foundry27](http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.bsp/wiki/TiAm335Beaglebone). There is a higher version 6.6.0 and I tested it, the result is same.

The following is a list of files under `/dev` directory:

[image: files]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Start devc-ser8250 with five ports (the last four preset to 38400
>   baud):
>
> ```
> devc-ser8250 3f8,4 -b 38400 280,3 288,3 290,3 298,3 &
> ```

It is from [QNX 6.6.0 documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide%2Ftopic%2Ffsystems_NFS.html&resultof=%22mount%22%20%22remote%22%20%22filesystem%22)

Comment: It works! In Beaglebone black, the driver name is "devc-seromap", and I added serial 2 by runing command "devc-seromap -e -F -b115200 -c48000000/16 0x48022000^2,73"

Comment: Which 0x48022000 is the uart1's peripheral memory address, 73 is the interrupt number used by uart1. Thanks for your help !